# Optimality of some Algorithm under Non-Convexity - "Pie in the Sky"?

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, optimization

I always come across mathematical proofs that show some optimization algorithms are guaranteed to converge to a global minimum, provided the function is Convex (and deterministic). For example:

- In Linear Programming, algorithms such as the Simplex Method are said to eventually reach the global minimum of a function, provided the function is Convex (and deterministic).
- Take the Gradient Descent algorithm - the classical Gradient Descent algorithm is also said to eventually the reach the global minimum of a function, provided the function is Convex (and deterministic).

However, most functions in the real world are Non-Convex (and non-deterministic). This means that in theory, the above optimization algorithms are not guaranteed to converge to the global minimum of a function (note: I am not sure if it is strictly impossible for these algorithms to converge to global minimums of Non-Convex Functions - or if it is sometimes possible, but not guaranteed). I have heard that researchers are always trying to develop new optimization algorithms that "in practice" might perform better on Non-Convex Functions, but still there have been no major results established that prove the optimality (i.e. guarantee of global convergence) of optimization algorithms on Non-Convex functions.

This leads me to my question:

- It seems that mathematically, it is difficult to prove that optimization algorithm will converge to the global minimum of a Non-Convex Function. Conceptually, this is often justified by stating that Non-Convex Functions are "bumpy" and can have many local minimums - and optimization algorithms often get "stuck" in these local minimums and thus the "guarantee of converging to a global minimum" is voided. **But from a mathematical perspective - why is it easier to prove the optimality of some optimization algorithms on Convex Functions vs. Non-Convex Functions?**
- **Have we determined whether it is even mathematically possible to prove the optimality of optimization algorithms on Non-Convex Functions - is it possible that proving the optimality of optimization algorithms on Non-Convex Functions might be a "pie in the sky"(I.e. impossible)? Mathematically, what exactly has been "preventing" us from accomplishing this?**

Thanks!

**Note:** My understanding is that real world data has inherent "mathematical volatility" (i.e. if you were to collect the same data under the same conditions at a different point in time, the data might be different) and functions that are constructed using real world data will also be inherently "mathematical volatile", i.e. non-deterministic. Standard mathematical proofs for convergence of optimization algorithms for even Convex Functions generally assumes that the function is non-deterministic. I am not sure to what extent a function being non-deterministic influences and complicates the theoretical convergence of optimization algorithms.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by a “non-deterministic function”? What would it even mean to optimise such a “function”?

Comment: @ Mark Saving: Thank you for your reply! In statistics and machine learning, suppose I have some data points (measurements) - I might assume for instance that these data points can be well-modelled using a 3rd order polynomial model. Once I "fit" this 3rd order polynomial model to these data points, the resulting function (e.g. y = 3.1*x^3 + 2.21 * x^2 + 5*x + 0.23)  could be interpreted as "non-deterministic" seeing as these measurements have an inherent level of measurement error and random error.

Comment: It is possible that if I collected the same data tomorrow and "fit" the same 3rd order polynomial function to this new data, the resulting function might be slightly different - e.g. . y = 3.2*x^3 + 2.65* x^2 + 5.01*x + 2.1 . This is what I meant by a "non-deterministic function". Optimizing a deterministic function would be like : find the value of "x" that minimizes the function y = 3x^2 for example. Now that I typed this all out - I realize that it might be better to just take out any reference of "non-deterministic" and let the question only be about Convex vs. Non-Convex.