# Show that partial derivatives of a function are not continuous

Tags: continuity, partial-derivative, piecewise-continuity

Define $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} &\text{if}\, (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\
      0 &\text{if}\, (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}
$$

I have found that for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{y(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{x(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

I don't know how to show that these are not continuous functions.
I know there exists similar questions, but there is no duplicate of this question since I am asking about the continuity of the partial derivatives **not** of $f(x,y)$

Comment: Of course, these *are* continuous functions. You haven't even considered $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

Comment: @ John Warts: great question! but why is this important to know whether or not the partial derivative of a function is continuous or not? does this have any practical implications? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By direct calculation, you'll get $f_x(0, 0) = 0$ and $f_y(0, 0) = 0$. So you can check whether $\lim_{(x, y)\to(0, 0)}f_x(x, y) = 0$ or not, and the same for $f_y$. Can you find suitable path s.t $f_x$ does not converge to $0$?

Comment: How does direct calculation give value zero?

Comment: @ riemann18: great answer! but why is this important to know whether or not the partial derivative of a function is continuous or not? does this have any practical implications? Thanks!

Comment: @aschepler You can use the definition. $f_x(0, 0) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x, 0)-f(0, 0)}{x}$, so you can put the value $f(0, 0) = 0$ and $f(x, 0) = 0$ which is from the definition of $f$.

Comment: @stats_noob There is a theorem, that if a function $f$ has partial derivatives near the point $(a, b)$ and if the partials are continuous at $(a, b)$, then $f$ is differentiable(though differentiability again needs to be defined properly).

Comment: @ riemann : thank you for your reply! I had a general question about derivatives/optimization over here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4454540/optimality-of-some-algorithm-under-non-convexity-pie-in-the-sky - can you please check this out if you have time? Thank you!